# Как прикрепить кнопки внизу экрана?

Tags: android

Какой лучше всего использовать layout, чтобы прикрепить кнопки к нижней части экрана?Остальная часть должна прокручиваться...

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `RelativeLayout` и выставьте `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` для контейнера с кнопками.

Comment: наверное все же `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: Да, конечно же. Писал по памяти, ошибся.

Comment: Почему то, если вставляю в ScrollView список ListView

 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

то вижу всего лишь одну строчку списка

Comment: @sitevRu, и это ожидаемое поведение. Смотрим [документацию][1]:
> **You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView**, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling.

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html